# Is it possible to link data from R forms with Google Drive SDK

Tags: r, google-drive-api

I wanted to get some feedback on the plausibility of this project before I grind too many gears.

Try running:

```
install.packages("webutils")
library(webutils)
demo_rhttpd()
```

Enter info. into the form and get a text file in the browser window after submitting it.

Now, is it possible to get R code to host this form in Google Drive:
https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en

If not, why?

and is it possible to get R code to store the submitted form data in a Google Spreadsheet:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

If not, why?